# Concatenate values of a specific column seperated by semi colon in sql server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL SERVER 2016.

```
DECLARE @TESTTABLE TABLE
        (
        VenNumber INT,
        VenName VARCHAR(60),
        Ctypes  varchar(50),
        Purpose varchar(500),
        Country varchar(20)
        )
  


Insert @TESTTABLE

SELECT 23248,'Automoci','Organisation','Business','USA' UNION ALL
SELECT 23248,'Automoci','Organisation','Purchase order confirmation','USA' UNION ALL
SELECT 23248,'Automoci','Organisation','Supply Chain Contact','USA' UNION ALL
SELECT 23642,'Palau','Person','Business','ES' UNION ALL
SELECT 23642,'Palau','Person','Supply Chain Contact','ES' UNION ALL
SELECT 23642,'Palau','Person','Invoice','ES'
```

**when values of VenNumber is same and  ctypes = 'Organisation' then concatenate purpose value seperated by semicolon (;)**

Output:

```
 23248  Automoci    Organisation    Business;Purchase order confirmation;Supply Chain Contact   USA
 23642  Palau   Person  Business    ES
 23642  Palau   Person  Supply Chain Contact    ES
 23642  Palau   Person  Invoice ES
```

Kindly share suggestion

Comment: If you're having problems with a specific query feel free to edit your question to include that to show what you've tried, but StackOverflow isn't a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for string aggregation:

```
select VenName, Ctypes, country,
       string_agg(purpose, '; ') within group (order by purpose) as purposes
from @testtable tt
group by VenName, Ctypes, country,
         (case when VenName <> 'Organisation' then purpose end);
```

Note the additional `GROUP BY` expression to keep the non-organizations split into separate rows.

Comment: i am getting error as "'string_agg' is not a recognized built-in function name." i am using sql server 2016

Comment: Please help if it is possible in sql server 2016